# How to convert number to text to avoid query cost

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, type-conversion, string-aggregation

I have a query condition as below

```
numeric_column = text_column::numeric
```

Getting lower cost and fine for my scenario. But when I am passing this through hibernate, getting error

```
"Not all named parameters have been set [:numeric]"
```

So, I have modified my query as below

```
to_char(numeric_column, '9999999') = text_column
```

Its working fine, But my query explain showing more cost for the above query.

How can I avoid that?. Is there any alternative to do that?

(I am using Postgresql-9.1 and hibernate version is 4.1.0)

Comment: I found an alternative for now. numeric_column = cast (text_column as numeric). explain cost is ok for me.

Comment: The **real** question is: why are you storing numbers in a text column in the first place?

Comment: @horse, i am taking that value from third party table where they have stored as text.

Comment: what's the size of dataset? @Spike

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at [**Indexes on Expressions**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/indexes-expressional.html) and compare results. **B-tree** index should be fine by default:

```
CREATE INDEX numeric_column_astext_btree ON your_table ((numeric_column::TEXT));
```

Query can be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE numeric_column::TEXT = text_column;
```

But I agree with comments above that it makes much more sense to use appropriate types. You also did not specified indexes structure `\d your_table` and `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.